# PHP salt generator

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP function that generates salts for use with password hashing:

```
function getSalt() {
     $charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/\\][{}\'";:?.>,<!@#$%^&*()-_=+|';
     $randString = "";
     $randStringLen = 64;

     while(strlen($randString) < $randStringLen) {
         $randChar = substr(str_shuffle($charset), mt_rand(0, strlen($charset)), 1);
         $randString .= $randChar;
     }

     return $randString;
}
```

To me, this seems like a secure salt generator because the use of the `while()` loop and string concatenation for every iteration of `substr()` and `str_shuffle` will potentially use the same character in `$charset` twice (as opposed to simply `str_shuffle()`'ing once).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not necessary for a salt to be perfectly random, it just should be *unique for every password* you save to defeat rainbow tables and and cracking several passwords at the same time. If it would be required to be perfectly random you would have to use a secure random number generator like [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).

---

That being said your algorithm looks overly complex to me. As you add a new character to your salt in every iteration of the loop you can use a `for` loop here: `for ($i = 0; $i < $randStringLen; $i++)`.

There also is no need for the `str_shuffle`, you are picking a random index from your character set anyway. Note that I have to subtract one from the string length, as everything is zero indexed here. In your version it did not matter, as you are not looping for a fixed number of iterations, but until your string is long enough. I would consider it a bug none-the-less. So this can be reduced to a simple:

```
substr($charset, mt_rand(0, strlen($charset) - 1), 1);
```

or even

```
$charset[mt_rand(0, strlen($charset) - 1)];
```

Further I suggest reordering your variables. Currently the “internal parameters” are interleaved with the return value (`randString`). I would move the return value down.

All in all your algorithm would look something like this:

```
function getSalt() {
     $charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/\\][{}\'";:?.>,<!@#$%^&*()-_=+|';
     $randStringLen = 64;

     $randString = "";
     for ($i = 0; $i < $randStringLen; $i++) {
         $randString .= $charset[mt_rand(0, strlen($charset) - 1)];
     }

     return $randString;
}
```

---

But in the end it does not matter how your salt generation algorithm looks like, as you should be using [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for the exact reason that you do not have to worry about these kind of issues!

Comment: Thank you for the direct critique without jumping straight to "use `password_hash()` for this!".

I do understand that every salt should be unique and not just random, but the random factor plays a part in a salt's uniqueness.

What is the advantage of using the `for()` loop over the `while()` loop in this scenario?

I was looking into `password_hash()` on PHP.net's manual and the reason I was reluctant to use that right away was because I want to store the salt in the database. From the looks of it, `password_hash()` returns the salt used, but how exactly would that salt be stored then?

Comment: @MatthewU. You *really* should use `password_hash`, though :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Debian Wheezy in this scenario which currently runs PHP 5.4, so `password_hash()` is not available for me. After looking into `password_hash()` examples further, I now have a thorough understanding of it and will be utilizing that now after I upgrade my system and packages. :)

Comment: @MatthewU. Use bcrypt then. You can reuse your salt generation function with a different charset.

Comment: @MatthewU. - there is a [password-hash-compatibility script](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for PHP 5.4 (and patched 5.3.7+) by ircmaxell on github. It uses the same "guts" - `mcrypt_create_iv()` using `dev/urand` for the salt, `bcrypt` for the KDF - but the back-and-forth between PHP and the binaries means it's just a little slower. You can use `function_exists()` to determine whether or not you need to load the script. The salt (and algo and settings for the algo) is stored in the returned hash string. You don't need another column to store the hash; `bcrypt` can extract it.

Comment: ... and if you (or your hosting provider) upgrade to PHP 5.5+, you won't need to change anything. Just remember to use `password_needs_rehash()` rigorously, use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` and it's as close to "set it and forget it" as you get in this business (which means keep up with the literature and change things when you need to).

Answer (score 2):

1. `mt_rand` is seeded by a 32 bit integer. So there is little point in generating a 384 bit string. You'll still only get 4 billion different salts.
2. PHP's bcrypt API will ignore anything beyond the first 128 bits and expects a Base64 encoded salt, so your salt isn't usable for that either.
3. To generate random numbers you can either use `mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)` or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or ([`random_bytes($size)`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/easy_userland_csprng) in php 7). Note that with the openssl variant you should check the second parameter to see if you got back good random data.

   Then encode the output with Base64.
4. Just use the `password_hash` API (php 5.5) or its polyfill on older versions. Its easy to use and secure.